# Why doesn't my system allow me to enter my Admin Password in Terminal when I try to flush my DNS Cache?

Tags: terminal, mac, password, dns

I've tried the `sudo killall mDNSResponder; sleep 2; echo macOS DNS Cache Reset` but when the Password symbol appears its locked and won't allow me to put in my Admin Password? Anyone ever seen this or know what might be going on? The reason I'm trying to do this is that my VPN connects fine but won't allow me to access the internet, which is why I thought I'd try to flush out my DNS cache, but its weird that it won't allow me to type in my password at the Password prompt. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It won't let you type anything, or what you type isn't visible and you THINK it won't let you type anything?  The sudo command does not echo your password back to you. 
 Using cookie-cutter commands found on the internet without knowing what they do is never a good idea.

Comment: It’s likely not a DNS issue.  Your VPN is configured so that all traffic is going through that connection.  Is this a work VPN?  As for your password, what happens when you type it and press enter?